# How to load WebGL Vertex and Fragment Shaders in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, three.js, glsl

Let me put my question upfront, and then share related details: **Is there a way we can use/load (fix parsing errors) WebGL shaders in ReactJS? Are there any loaders available?**

After struggling for hours Googling for a way to be able to use shader files (i.e., Vertex and Fragment Shaders), I have found no conclusive solution yet.

***When I do this in ReactJS app:***

- `require('../shaders/particle.vert')`
- `import particleVert from '../shaders/particle.vert'`

***I get this error:***

```
ERROR in ./src/particles/src/shaders/particle.vert 3:10
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

***This is how I'm using those shaders in my react-app code:***

```
const material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
        uniforms,
        vertexShader: glslify(require('../shaders/particle.vert')),
        fragmentShader: glslify(require('../shaders/particle.frag')),
        // vertexShader: glslify(particleVert),
        // fragmentShader: glslify(particleFrag),
        depthTest: false,
        transparent: true,
        // blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending
});
```

---

Here is a screenshot displaying entire log of the issue:

[image]

Comment: What bundler are you using? Webpack? Parcel? That bundler is responsible for turning `require('textfile.frag')` into the right thing. It doesnt know how to handle .frag and .vert files right now.

Comment: I'm using a basic react-app [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

Answer (score 5):

I think you are going outside the lines that create-react-app sets up for you. That means it's time to eject your app, and customize its build process.

Run:

```
npm run eject
```

Now you need to configure webpack to allow importing of frag and vert files as a string. This is done with [webpack's 'raw-loader'](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader)

```
npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

Now add some lines of configuration to the webpack.config.js file you should have in your directory root. You looking for where it defines `module: { rules: { /*...*/ } }`. Add the following rule to the array:

```
// Require .vert and .frag as raw text.
{
  test: /\.(vert|frag)$/i,
  use: 'raw-loader',
}
```

The `test` is a regex to run on the filename, so this says any file ending in `.vert` or `.frag` should use the `raw-loader`

Comment: I could be wrong but I also suspect you want to call `glslify` at build time not runtime.

Answer (score 1):

if nothing works try importing it as a string constant

```
const vertex = `
varying vec2 vertexUV;
varying vec3 vertexNormal;

void main(){
    vertexUV = uv;
    vertexNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}`;

export default vertex
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

- with new react versions (with webpack > 5), we have to use asset/source.
- No npm/yarn install needed

Note: the project has to be ejected.
Check more details https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/:

```
{
  test: /\.(glsl|vert|frag)$/,
  type: 'asset/source',
},
```

Comment: It's unclear what this means - where does this go? What does it refer to? Are you assuming the project has been ejected from CRA?

Comment: Yes the project has to be ejected. This should be inside webpack configuration. You can check more details here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

Answer (score 0):

react-three-fiber/drei is your best bet for a lightweight wrapper for three.js' rawshadermaterial. Here is the documentation:

https://docs.pmnd.rs/drei/shaders/shader-material

The docs are pretty straight forward and you can still import external files with glsify