# How to use glsl shader in react

Tags: reactjs, three.js, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am using Threejs inside react project. I want to import .glsl file in a component and using to create a react material. It is throwing error

vertex.glsl

```
uniform vec2 uFrequency;
uniform float uTime;

varying vec2 vUv;
varying float vElevation;

void main()
{
    vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    float elevation = sin(modelPosition.x * uFrequency.x - uTime*4.0) * 0.01;
    elevation += sin(modelPosition.y * uFrequency.y - uTime*2.0) * 0.01;

    modelPosition.z += elevation;

    vec4 viewPosition = viewMatrix * modelPosition;
    vec4 projectedPosition = projectionMatrix * viewPosition;

    gl_Position = projectedPosition;

    vUv = uv;
    vElevation = elevation;
}
```

fragment.glsl

```
uniform vec3 uColor;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;

varying vec2 vUv;
varying float vElevation;

void main()
{
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uTexture, vUv);
    textureColor.rgb *= vElevation * 2.0 + 0.85;
    gl_FragColor = textureColor;
    // gl_FragColor = vec4(vUv, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Imports

```
import vertexShader from "../../shaders/vertex.glsl";
import fragmentShader from "../../shaders/fragment.glsl";
```

Using vertexShader and fragmentShader in creating a shaderMaterial

```
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                  vertexShader: vertexShader,
                  fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
                  uniforms: {
                    uFrequency: { value: new THREE.Vector2(2, 0) },
                    uTime: { value: 0 },
                    uColor: { value: new THREE.Color("orange") },
                    uTexture: { value: cards[0] },
                  },
                });
```

I am getting this error:

react_devtools_backend.js:4026 THREE.WebGLProgram: Shader Error 1282 - VALIDATE_STATUS false

Program Info Log: Vertex shader is not compiled.

VERTEX

ERROR: 0:57: '/' : syntax error

52: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
53:   attribute vec4 skinIndex;
54:   attribute vec4 skinWeight;
55: #endif
56:

> 57: /static/media/vertex.b0f036220a7b64047a36.glsl
> FRAGMENT

ERROR: 0:31: '/' : syntax error

26: vec4 LinearTosRGB( in vec4 value ) {
27:   return vec4( mix( pow( value.rgb, vec3( 0.41666 ) ) * 1.055 - vec3( 0.055 ), value.rgb * 12.92, vec3( lessThanEqual( value.rgb, vec3( 0.0031308 ) ) ) ), value.a );
28: }
29: vec4 linearToOutputTexel( vec4 value ) { return LinearToLinear( value ); }
30:

> 31: /static/media/fragment.69a947255b842e5a60dd.glsl

Can someone please help how to use .glsl file in react.

Comment: Did you exclude glsl files from the react compiler ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load WebGL Vertex and Fragment Shaders in ReactJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778436/how-to-load-webgl-vertex-and-fragment-shaders-in-reactjs)